# EWS - Get current user (sender) contact information vb.net

Tags: vb.net, email, exchangewebservices, contacts

I'm currently developping a program that will serve to send emails via company's EWS. the code for sending the message works perfectly but i also need to get some data about the sender of the email. It means, when a user sends the email to me, I need to see his position and address.
I'm struggling for more then a week to find a way to define the sender in the code and his contact details. And still nothing found so far.
Will appreacite your helf.

My code so far:

```
Dim url As String = "https://.../ews/Exchange.asmx"
    exch.Url = New System.Uri(url)
    exch.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    exch.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(TextBox2.Text, TextBox1.Text)
    ' exch.AutodiscoverUrl("myemail")
    'exch.ResolveName("", ResolveNameSearchLocation.ContactsThenDirectory, True)
    Dim message As New EmailMessage(exch)
    message.Subject = "Новое заявление (АП) - " & ComboBox1.SelectedItem
    message.Body = "Добрый день!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Прошу обработать заявление - " & ComboBox1.SelectedItem
    For Each f In attfiles
        message.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(f)
    Next
    message.ToRecipients.Add(email)
    message.SendAndSaveCopy()
```

Comment: include his position and address in message body.If you should ask user just add two another inputs(position and address field)  so users can write those.

Comment: yeah, this could be a decision, but I want to minimise any hand input in the program. i want to retrieive this info from sender contact information after sender clicks the button "Send" (all this info is presented in everyone's Contact properties).

Comment: define what you mean contact information. Is it stored on your database or is it on device. Are you talking about Windows Phone?

Comment: by contact info, I mean position, organisation, full name etc - all info stored about the sender in his Contact item on Exchange server

Comment: I now notice ews tag which was Exchange server. I am not familiar with this Api. You can check how address can be otained. Look api or Search for mostly in c# there can be many examples. Then as I said you can include that info into body message or you can again obtain it using email address

Comment: Check api docs .here is how to obtain http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220498(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks. It seems like I am moving in a right direction to obtain the sender's email when he clicks button "Send": one way - via ResolveName, another (more "dirty" one) - via posting item (postItem) and getting poster email... On the other hand - still not sure this will work

Comment: Another opened question - how to find the exact contact from Contacts folder - the example from MSDN proposes to search with "for each" cycle which will take a while, taking into account the number of eployees in company... also, I did not find there any sign of how to indicate what exactly to search... Sorry, I am newbee to EWS... and not good in C#

Comment: Guys! Question still actual. Please assist!

Comment: Please provide more business rules for your application.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the correct path by using the ResolveNames operation. Using the sender SMTP address, use ResolveNames to get back a list of potential matches for the sender.  The foreach in the example is just so you can see each result. Since you are passing an SMTP address, it is very likely that your result set may be no more than a few contacts.

It sounds like one of your assumptions is that the sender always has an entry in the user's Contacts folder. Is that always true? Can the sender not exist as an entries in the recipients Contact folder but have an entry in Active Directory? You are doing the right thing to cover both possibilities by using the ResolveNameSearchLocation.ContactsThenDirectory option.

Resolve names works well if you have a display name or SMTP address. You also ask about how to find a specific contact. You mention that want to search the Contacts folder, but you are concerned about the number of employees. Do all employees have contact items in the target mailboxes? To search for specific contacts, learn about [EWS search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579421%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).